# Why does my method for $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-5x^2}}$ not give an arcsin?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

The integral is

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-5x^2}}$$
I was trying:

$$=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{5(\frac{4}{5}-x^2)}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{5}-x^2}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\int \frac{dx}
{\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{\frac{4}{5}}\right)^2-x^2}}$$
Let $x = \sqrt{\frac{4}{5}}\sin\theta$ and $dx = \sqrt{\frac{4}{5}}\cos\theta\, d\theta.$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}\int \frac{d\theta}{\cos\theta}$$
That integral does not have the form of the answer which  involves $\arcsin$.
Why this trig substitution does not work?

Comment: your last integral is not correct.

Comment: @Yimin check new edit

Comment: still not right

Comment: @Yimin where is my mistake?

Comment: Please use descriptive titles for your posts.

Comment: you forgot to replace dx with cos

Comment: @Yimin I did its juts that I cancel out with he cosine in the denominator

Comment: there is only one cos on the denom, there is a square root

Comment: yea I  edit now is 1/cos

Comment: I get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\int \frac{\cos\theta}{|\cos\theta|}d\theta$ which makes no sense either. It would be interesting to know if there is some subtle mistake or just a "stupid" one

Comment: @PeterMelech turns out in my equation 4 that integral is in the form such that the answer is arcsin(x/a) but I don't know why the trig substitution does not work, why did you get an absolute value.?

Comment: Where is $d\theta$?

Comment: @BobDobbs I skipped some steps in my final result

Comment: @samsamradas Then you may also let $dx=1$ if you wanna skip more.

Comment: @BobDobbs I see what you mean I edit my question

Comment: @samsamradas Bob Dobb´s answer also clarifies this point, in the end there was no mistake but a bit of confusion on my side

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-5x^2)}}$$
Samsamradas factored $5$. Instead, I will factor $4$.
$$\int \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{1-(\tfrac{\sqrt5x}2)^2)}}$$
Now, let $\frac{\sqrt5 x}2=\sin\theta$ so that $\theta=\arcsin(\tfrac{\sqrt5 x}{2})$. Then, $\frac{\sqrt5 dx}2=\cos\theta\,d\theta$ and hence $dx=\frac2{\sqrt5}\cos\theta\,d\theta.$ The integral becomes
$$\int\frac{\frac2{\sqrt5}\cos\theta\,d\theta}{2\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}$$
By using the trigonometric identity $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, we have $\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}=|\cos\theta|.$ We may assume that $-\frac\pi 2\leq\theta\leq\frac\pi 2$ and hence $|\cos\theta|=\cos\theta.$

We end up with
$$\frac1{\sqrt5}\int d\theta=\frac1{\sqrt5}\theta+C\\=\frac1{\sqrt5}\arcsin(\tfrac{\sqrt5 x}2)+C$$

Comment: why mine is wrong?

Comment: $\cos\theta$ s cancel in mine. In yours?

Comment: I see I forgot to apply the sqrt in cos^2

Comment: thank you Bob Dobbs

Comment: @samsamradas Nothing... I hope that other/new contributors do better.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to square when substituting back in. I believe you can solve relatively easily once you square and use the fact that $1-sin^2$ is $cos^2$. Feel free to review the derivative of $arccos$ if you need inspiration.

Comment: Why don't you write a detailed answer where you used $1-\sin^2\theta=\cos^2\theta$ identity?